# Get int value from method, which executes on background thread

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm using Google Architecture Components, especially Room.

In my Dao i have this method:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos")
int getPersistedPhotosSize();
```

And i need to execute it in my Repository to check if *persisted photos size* is 0.

So i gotta execute this method on background and get the value from it.

Now i perform this operation like this:

```
   public int getNumRowsFromFeed() {
   final int[] rows = new int[1];
   Completable.fromAction(() -> rows[0] = photosDao.getPersistedPhotosSize())
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .blockingAwait();
   return rows[0];
}
```

But i guess it's **not** the best way to do it.

So how can i get the value the right way? Especially i want to do it **without** RX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your DAO the function to get the photo count doesn't use either `LiveData` nor `RX`. So instead of wrapping the code afterwards in a `Completable`, you can basically use any Android Async technology, like `AsyncTask`.

```
public class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    public interface Callback {
        void onPhotoCount(int count);
    }

    private final Callback callback;

    public LoadTask(Callback callback) {
         this.callback = callback;
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return photosDao.getPersistedPhotosSize();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
         callback.onPhotoCount(result);
    }

}

...

new LoadTask(photoCount -> {
    // Do stuff with value,e.g. update ui.
}).execute();
```

This is basically just a proposal, of course you can use Threads, Handler as well.

P.S: From my point of view, this example shows one advantage of the `Rx` development. You get the callback stuff for free, without defining anything. And you can cancel the Rx chain for example due to lifecycle events. This is not implemented in this example.

Comment: Of course, i use rx as well on my project, but i decided to learn Threads from scratch.

Comment: Is it normal that i wrap int, which i need to return in a 1-element array?

Comment: In your approach you execute the `Completable` on the IO scheduler, but you await the result on the main thread, which is still blocked until the result arrives. Basically you can call your `getPersistedPhotosSize` function directly (but Room would complain), it has the same effect. Regarding the 1-array approach: I only use it in UnitTests, where I also work with blocking observables.